# Secciones antes y después de loguearse!

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un sitio web en php y html en el cual tengo usuarios registrados y quiero que al iniciar sesión el usuario no le aparezca el enlace de iniciar sesión ni tampoco el de crear cuenta, ya que al usuario normal sin loguearse si le debe de aparecer, en la imagen están las secciones que tengo y quiero que al loguearme desaparezca iniciar sesión y crear una cuenta.
gracias de antemano.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esto es lo que quiero hacer quiero que no aparezca iniciar sesión y crear usuario cuando este logueado, ya que me logueo y me muestra todas las secciones asi como se ve en la imagen.

Comment: Si no compartes el codigo es dificil ayudarte. Te recomiendo que leas [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Si usas sesiones para el inicio de sesión pon un if en el html donde pongas que si no existe ninguna sesión no lo muestre o muestre otra cosa, pero sin compartir el código no podremos ayudarte mucho.

Comment: ya lo solucione con el if, pero muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!